# "Configuration Settings" for views and procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We are running Oracle 11g and have processes that do periodic exports based on views.  Those views filter the results based on fields in their data, in this case "semester" and "year" (e.g. SPRING 2022).  The semesters we want to include change from semester to semester and currently we save those settings in a table.  So, for example:

```
SELECT NAME, SEMESTER FROM STUDENTSTABLE WHERE SEMESTER = (SELECT CURRENT_SEMESTER FROM SETTINGS_TABLE) OR SEMESTER = (SELECT NEXT_SEMESTER FROM SETTING_STABLE);
```

That `SETTINGS_TABLE` has one row and a lot of columns.

My question is is there an alternative way to save those settings other than a table or hard coding them into the view?

Comment: Unless the export utility you are using can provide the values (as from a command line), in such a way that it could query the data as shown, then probably not. Keeping them in the table has the advantage of making them available to any tool or app accessing the data, so that all tools can have a consistent view of the data. If you move it out of the database, you'd have to figure out a unique replacement solution for every tool and keep them synchronized.

Comment: Thanks pmdba, that's what I figured.  As for the way too many columns I guess that just boils down to design and foresight.  Maybe in this case, having two columns, setting and value, would be better than using the column name as the setting name.

Comment: It really depends what application you use to export the data. Assuming that you might use the sql*plus cli, you could just use substitution variables that can be set on the command line. https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/sql*plus-substitution-variables-define-variables-and-parameters-in-sql-queries